# bash: how to intercept every command

Tags: bash

Is there a way to intercept every command given to `bash`? I can intercept a particular command, e.g., `cd` by defining a function `cd()` and I can do that for one-command-at-a-time for other commands as well. But can I write a function which gets called before every command is executed? I want to do some bookkeeping of commands, and then executed the command.

Michał Šrajer's idea `PS4='$(echo $(date) $(history 1) >> /tmp/trace.txt) TRACE: '` looks very promising but here is the output I get:

```
$ ping www.google.com
 TRACE: ping www.google.com
PING www.l.google.com (74.125.224.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 74.125.224.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=3.77 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.224.52: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=2.33 ms
^C
--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.334/3.054/3.774/0.720 ms
  TRACE: echo -ne '\033]0;myhost.com /home/yogeshwer/github/myproject\007'
  TRACE: grep -e '\* '
  TRACE: git branch
  TRACE: sed 's/^..\(.*\)/ {\1}/'
```

And `Wed Aug 3 12:47:27 PDT 2011 6672 ping www.google.com` get written in /tmp/trace.txt exactly 5 times. The four other ones comes from my definition of `PS1` where I run the following command: `$(git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e "\* " | sed "s/^..\(.*\)/ {\1}/")`. Two questions:

- Is it possible to write the command to `/tmp/trace.txt` exactly?
- And more importantly, is it possible to not clutter the output of the command, but only write the command to `/tmp/trace.txt`?

I am so excited about the possibility of being able to record commands from all my bash sessions in one place!

Comment: `.bash_history` is not sufficient for your needs, I take it?

Comment: Note that `.bash_history` is updated only when the shell exits.

Comment: `.bash_history` is not sufficient. `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed just before the command is executed (I think), but I don't have access to "command about to be executed" when `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed. What will be perfect is to grab the command "about to be executed next", do some statistics on it (how many times it has been executed etc) and write that to some log file, and then actually execute the command.

Comment: You can't remove the extra output, PS4 variable is used for debugging that's where the extra output is from. As for the multiple occurrences of the command I think it is due to the fact that the | operator executes each command in a subshell

Answer (score 10):

You can set the PS4 variable, which is evaluated for every command being executed just before the execution if trace is on:

```
PS4='$(echo $(date) $(history 1) >> /tmp/trace.txt) TRACE: '
```

Then, enable trace:

```
set -x
```

To stop tracing, just:

```
set +x
```

Comment: This sounds _very_ promising. I have edited the question (because I find it hard to write chunks of code in the comment). I am quite close, but cannot figure out the last step.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone finds this question through Google, I solved this by adding the following to my `~/.bashrc`.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo "$(date +"%Y/%m/%d (%H:%M)") $(history 1 |cut -c 7-)" >> /tmp/trace'
export PROMPT_COMMAND
```

This results in /tmp/trace having contents such as

```
2015/01/21 (14:34) pwd
2015/01/21 (14:36) less /tmp/trace
2015/01/21 (14:36) cd Documents
2015/01/21 (14:36) cd ..
2015/01/21 (14:36) ls -la
2015/01/21 (14:36) pwd
2015/01/21 (14:36) echo "helloWorld"
```

- `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed after every command that is run through bash
- `$(date +"%Y/%m/%d (%H:%M)")` prints the date and time
- `$(history 1 |cut -c 7-)` prints the command

  - `cut -c 7-` removes the number that `history` would otherwise include
- `>> /tmp/trace` appends the complete string to the file you specify. (I'd advise against anything in `/tmp/` unless you want it to be deleted when you restart the computer.)

Answer (score 4):

`$PROMPT_COMMAND`, if set, contains a command to execute before printing the prompt (`$PS1`).  Set it to the name of a function that captures the output of `history 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use trap with DEBUG to do this, like `trap 'a oneliner in here' DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about intercepting every command but in some versions of Linux every command gets logged to ~/.bash_history.  You could either figure out how that works or just parse that file to see the last command.