# Audit bash commands for bash RPG

Tags: c++, bash

I want to be able to write a program that when you type in commands, it will do things like count the amount of times you've used `cd`. Something similar to this:

```
[ : ~ $] cd public_html
Congratulations! You've earned the Badge 'cd master!'. Level up!
```

All my C++ file consists of so far is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
        if (argv[i] == "cd")
            std::cout << "Badge earned 'cd master!' +5120 experience points" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As it reflects one attempted solution involving:

```
#!/bin/sh
bash | tee ./main
```

and

```
bind 'RETURN: "echo $(!!) | tee ~/.main \n"'
```

I've decided to go with

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history | tail -n1'
```

But that would mean having to parse the output.

What's the easiest way of accomplishing this?

**edit**

Here's what I've managed to produce:

```
#!/bin/sh
export COUNTER=0
export MAXWIDTH=10
export TNL=1000
update_prompt() {
  export PS1="> "
}
cd() {
  COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 25));
  echo +25;
  builtin cd $@;
}
help() {
  echo "custom commands are: score";
}
score() {
  echo $COUNTER"/"$TNL
  BAR=$(yes "#" | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n')
  OVERLAY=$(yes "%" | head -n 10 | tr -d '\n')
  WIDTH=$(echo "$COUNTER*$MAXWIDTH/$TNL" | bc)
  FIRST=${BAR:0:WIDTH}
  SECOND=${OVERLAY:0:$((MAXWIDTH-WIDTH))}
  echo "["$FIRST$SECOND"]"
}
exit() {
    echo "Bye bye";
    builtin exit $@;
}
export -f update_prompt
export -f cd # export the function
export -f help
export -f score
export -f exit

bash # run subshell with the exported functions
update_prompt
```

Comment: And what badge would you award to someone who says: `while : ; do cd $HOME; done`?

Comment: @devnull This is for personal usage. I don't use the shell except for when I need to.

Comment: This is a really cute idea, I'd love to see the result :)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You can also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930527/bash-how-to-intercept-every-command

Comment: @devnull if you have ignoredups in you history config then you would only see one `cd` entry in your history.

Comment: @RedX Is that the _default_?  __NO__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to overwrite the `cd` command of your shell inside the shell itself. For example, in Bash or ZSH:

```
cd() {
  echo "Congratulations";
  builtin cd $@;
}
```

(This is for example used in projects like [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv).)

You can do the same for all other commands. You can also call your C++ code from there.

If you want to put that into a script, e.g. name it `learn-bash.sh`:

```
cd() { ... }
export -f cd # export the function

bash # run subshell with the exported functions
```

---

Another solution, where you have much more power, but which is way more involved: take the source code of Bash (it's C) and extend it (by C or C++). Then you can basically do whatever you want. And you have everything directly there, i.e. the parsed commands, etc.

Comment: @RedX: Yes, but doesn't he have to do that anyway as he probably wants to have different behavior for different commands? Also, it avoids the problematic to parse the command manually in his external program.

Comment: @Albert: I suppose I can just write a one-time script so I don't have to type it out manually. Where would I put it, though?

Comment: Whereever you put it, you can import it by `source myscript.sh`. Or you can export it and spawn a subshell. I'll extend my question.

Answer (score 0):

After every command `COMMAND_PROMPT` is executed within bash. You could use that with `history` to see the last command used.

You can read [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/) on how PS1, PS2, PS3 and COMMAND_PROMPT work in bash.

There are a few answers on exactly this question already on SO:

[How can I intercept commands that contain a certain string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622583/how-can-i-intercept-commands-that-contain-a-certain-string)

[bash: how to intercept every command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930527/bash-how-to-intercept-every-command)

[bash: How to intercept command line and do various actions based on the contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652752/bash-how-to-intercept-command-line-and-do-various-actions-based-on-the-contents)

Comment: Yes I've looked at those links. I went with `PROMPT_COMMAND` because it has the cleanest output.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar a while ago, and here's the solution I've found.

You want to add the following lines to `.bashrc`:

```
hook() {
    whatever "$@"
}

invoke_hook() {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return
    local command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;
    hook "$command"
}

trap 'invoke_hook' DEBUG
```

Replace `whatever` with your C++ program. This will execute your hook before each command, and will pass the original command as the arguments.