# What is the bash variable $COMP_LINE and what does it do?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

What is the $COMP_LINE variable in bash scripting?  The [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) has the following to say.

> $COMP_LINE
>
> The current command line. This variable is available only in shell functions and external commands invoked by the programmable completion facilities (see Programmable Completion).

I don't understand what 'the current command line' means.

I am trying to pick apart [this script:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19403698/1344732) to see how it manages to intercept bash commands.

```
hook() {
    echo "$@"
}

invoke_hook() {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return
    local command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;
    hook "$command"
}

trap 'invoke_hook' DEBUG
```

I am running into trouble figuring out what the following line is supposed to do.

```
[ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return
```

I assume it some sort of check or test before you run the rest of the script, since [] is an alias for the bash test command, but since I can't read it I can't figure out what it's supposed to be testing.

Comment: Try putting `[ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return` into [explainshell.com](http://www.explainshell.com)

Comment: Good news: It explained [ -n ].  

Bad news: It doesn't know what $COMP_LINE is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bash, if you have a file `myfile.txt`, you can edit it with `nano myfi`<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This completes the filename automatically to save you typing, turning the command into `nano myfile.txt`. This is known as *filename completion*.

However, not all commands accept filenames. You may want to be able to do `ssh myho`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and have it complete to `ssh myhostname.example.com`.

Since `bash` can't possibly be expected to maintain this logic for all known and unknown commands across all systems, it has *programmable completion*.

With programmable completion, you can define a shell function to call that will get all hostnames from `.ssh/known_hosts` and make them available as completion entries.

When this function is invoked, it can examine the variable `$COMP_LINE` to see the command line it should give suggestions for. If you have set up  `complete -F myfunction ssh` and type `ssh myho`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then `myfunction` will run and `$COMP_LINE` will be set to `ssh myho`.

This functionality is used by your snippet to make the interceptor ignore commands run as a result of pressing Tab. Here it is with comments:

```
# This is a debug hook which will run before every single command executed 
# by the shell. This includes the user's command, but also prompt commands, 
# completion handlers, signal handlers and others.
invoke_hook() {

    # If this command is run because of tab completion, ignore it
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return

    # If the command is run to set up the prompt or window title, ignore it
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return

    # Get the last command from the shell history
    local command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`;

    # Run the hook with that command
    hook "$command"
}
```